# Signal R, Client javascript function not being called

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, signalr

I'm creating a chat room demo App,as i'm trying to learn signal r. My issue is that, my javascript client function is not being called, when attempted from the connect method in the chathub class on the server.

The LoadChatRoomContent client javascript function is only execute on page start. and not when i call it from the server hub function.

Any ideas?

**Client Side**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   **View Model**

var chatViewModel   = {
chat: $.connection.chatHub, 
connectToLobby: function () {
                this.chat.server.connect(this.userName());
    },
)


 $(function () {
   var chat = $.connection.chatHub;
   ko.applyBindings(chatViewModel);  

     // client side signalr functions

  chat.client.newUserHasJoined = function (userName) {
                //$('#chatContent').append(userName + "has joined");
                chatViewModel.latestChatContent.append(userName + "has joined");

                // update the users online list when a new member has joined
                chatViewModel.onlineUserList.push(userName);


            }; 

 chat.client.loadChatRoomContent = new function (messageHistory, userList) {

                // convert json string to javascript array so that it can be iterated.
                chatViewModel.onlineUserList = $.parseJSON(userList);

                //
                chatViewModel.latestChatContent = $.parseJSON(messageHistory);

                alert("it works");
            };    

           $.connection.hub.start();

        });

**Chat Hub**
 public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    List<connectedUsers> _currentUsers;

    // stores up to 100 messages
    List<string> _messageCache;

    public ChatHub(){
        _currentUsers = new List<connectedUsers>();
        _messageCache = new List<string>();
    }

    public void Connect(string userName)
    {
        // add new user to the list
        lock (_currentUsers)
        {
            _currentUsers.Add(new connectedUsers() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), userName = userName });
        }
        //let other users know of the new member
        Clients.AllExcept(Context.ConnectionId).newUserHasJoined(userName);

        // send chat messages and current UsersList to caller only
        // both objects sent as json string format.
        Clients.Caller.loadChatRoomContent( new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(_messageCache),new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(_currentUsers));
    }
```

}

Comment: I will be glad to help you if you cut your code in blocks, explaining what is each block. An improved question has an improved answer.

Comment: `loadChatRoomContent` is in the `Connect` method which is only called once per user once they have connected. I don't know how you expect that new content will be broadcast to all clients considered it is nested in the Connect function?